# How to close coded ui test builder that is open

Tags: coded-ui-tests

When I right click the method in the project that I created, and then select "Generate Code for Coded UI Test -> Use Coded UI Test Builder", I get the following error message " To edit or add another coded UI test, you must first close the Coded UI Test Builder that is open"

Now, I am not sure where do I have to go and close the already open Coded UI Test Builder?
Anyone?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Running multiple CodedUI test on same active desktop is not supported.
Then close that one which is already on:

[image]

Comment: Do you know how to close one instance of the coded UI test builder, if multiple are open? Is there a way to do that.  Also, I exited out of the program and opened it again. However, the problem continued to occur. When I checked task manager, I could only see one instance of the program? I also restarted  my machine.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that there is another instance of the test builder open, or at least visual studio sees that as the case (it is not supported to have more than one open at a time).  Verify that there is nothing open either in task manager, or by restarting.

Comment: I exited out of the program and opened it again. However, the problem continued to occur. When I checked task manager, I could only see one instance of the program? I also restarted  my machine.

Comment: @AN Something might've corrupted your install.  Try closing the open idea of VS, and then go into the installer and uninstall/reinstall the codedui portions

Comment: The problem is,  I am running it on a server by connecting to a remote desktop. So, I don't have permissions to restart the server :(

Comment: @AN You shouldn't need to restart to uninstall/reinstall those bits

Comment: Ok, Thanks don't know why but after two days the problem automatically went away. Still not sure what resolved it